# How do I tell a Dependency Injection container to share an instance?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

I am learning DI with Typescript (I use the tsyringe package in the example).

How can I tell a DI container that I want:

- one new Bar instance for every FooBar Instance (so no singleton) and
- Foo should reference the Bar instance of FooBar?

In the below example tsyringe creates two Bar instances (one in Foo and one for FooBar).

```
it("injects one Bar instance", () => {

  @injectable()
  class Bar {
    constructor() {}
    x = 1;
  }

  @injectable()
  class Foo {
    constructor(public myBar: Bar) {}
  }

  @injectable()
  class FooBar {
    constructor(public bar: Bar, public foo: Foo) {}
  }

  const fooBar = container.resolve(FooBar);
  fooBar.bar.x = 2;
  expect(fooBar.foo.myBar).toBe(2); // throws error (is 1)
});
```

Comment: That's depends on the API of the container you're using. Sometimes this is called transient lifetime as opposed to singleton lifetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tsyringe, one has to use the @scoped decorator:

```
  @scoped(Lifecycle.ResolutionScoped)
  class Bar {
    constructor() {}
  }
```